# Why won't the list delete function delete spaces?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop

```
string = "hello world i'm a new program"
words_length = []
length = 21
```

I'm using `re.split` to produce a list of words and spaces:

```
words = re.split('\w', string)
```

so:

```
words = ['hello', ' ', 'world', ' ', 'i', "'", 'm', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'new', ' ', 'program']

for x in words:
    words_length.append(len(x))

    for x in range(len(words)):
        if words_length < length:
        words_length += letters_length[x]
        line += words[x]    
        del words[x]
```

but at the end when I print the variables I get:

```
line = "helloworldi'manew"
words = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'program']
```

But what I want is:

```
line = "hello world i'm a new"
words = ['program']
```

How can I manage to do that?

Comment: You are skipping indices. Try with `[' ', 'a', ' ', 'b', ' ']` to see this has nothingto do with spaces.

Comment: Also, what are `letters_length` and `length`?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to modify a sequence while iterating over it.

Comment: *I have a list of words which were built with re.split('\w', string)* - I think you should start there - that's not a list of words - that's completely different...

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think so because I'm using `for x in range(len(letters)):`. therefore all indices in list are used. Don't you think ?

Comment: @NathanSchwarz you almost certainly have an XY problem here... what exactly is `string` and what do you want from it?

Comment: `letters_length` and `length` are `int`

Comment: @JonClements `string` here would be : 'a b c'

Comment: @NathanSchwarz: no, because you are *deleting from the list*.

Comment: @NathanSchwarz: why are you deleting from `letters` in the first place?

Comment: ok sorry I didn't explain the thing very well : let say you have string with a length of 50. Now I want to put in an other string which max length is 30 all the words which fit in it (so you add each words length until it reaches 30).

Comment: @NathanSchwarz: if your 'words' are all the same length, just use `string[:max_length].rstrip()`. That's guaranteed to be shorter and no whitespace at the end.

Comment: But you don't want to erase the end of the first string (with a length of 20) because you want to get it back later. So you want to erase the first 30 charaters of it

Comment: @MartijnPieters no the words are not the same length

Comment: @NathanSchwarz are you trying to implement your own [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/textwrap.html)?

Comment: @NathanSchwarz: your example implied they were; both in the input sample containing only single characters and the use of the variable `letters`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *skipping indices* because you are deleting characters from your list.

Each time you delete a character, everything to the *right* of that character shifts up one step to the left, and their index goes down by one. But your `x` index still goes up by one so now you are referencing a later element in the list:

1. first iteration of the for loop:

   ```
   x == 0
   words == ['hello', ' ', 'world', ' ', 'i', "'", 'm', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'new', ' ', 'program']
   #        0        1    2        3    4    5    ...
   words[x] == 'hello'

   del words[x]
   words == [' ', 'world', ' ', 'i', "'", 'm', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'new', ' ', 'program']
   #         0    1        2    3    4    5    ...
   ```
2. second iteration of your loop:

   ```
   x == 1
   words == [' ', 'world', ' ', 'i', "'", 'm', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'new', ' ', 'program']
   #         0    1        2    3    4    5    ...
   words[x] == 'world'

   del words[x]
   words == [' ', ' ', 'i', "'", 'm', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'new', ' ', 'program']
   #         0    1    2    3    4    5    ...
   ```
3. third iteration of your loop

   ```
   x == 2
   words == [' ', ' ', 'i', "'", 'm', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'new', ' ', 'program']
   #         0    1    2    3    4    5    ...
   words[x] == 'i'

   del words[x]
   words == [' ', ' ', "'", 'm', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'new', ' ', 'program']
   #         0    1    2    3    4    5    ...
   ```

Don't remove entries from your list until at least *after* looping; you don't need to have them removed during the loop:

```
line = []
current_length = 0
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    current_length += len(word)
    if current_length > length:
        i -= 1
        break
    line.append(word)
# here i is the index of the last element of words actually used
words = words[i + 1:]  # remove the elements that were used.
line = ''.join(line)
```

or you could remove words (from a reversed list for efficiency), but then use a `while` loop and test for the accumulated length instead:

```
line = []
current_length = 0
reversed_words = words[::-1]
while reversed_words:
    l = len(reversed_words[-1])
    if current_length + l > length:
        break
    line.append(reversed_words.pop())
    current_length += l
words = reversed_words[::-1]
line = ''.join(line)
```

However, if you are trying to apply line-length wrapping to a Python string, you could avoid re-inventing that wheel by using the [`textwrap` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) instead. It can do line-wrapping within a maximum length for you with ease:

```
wrapped = textwrap.fill(string, length)
```